# GGplot - how to not treat points as outliers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the below script, outliers on the boxplot are shown as individual scatter points. Instead, I would like the creation of the boxplot to include these and to *not* treat these points as outliers. Consequently, the box would be extended to include them.

```
ggplot(imp,aes(Group,LWG,fill=Group))+geom_boxplot()
```

As per the below picture, the bottom of the left boxplot would extend downwards further.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to modify the definition of a boxplot? I'm not understanding "Consequently, the box would be extended to include them." Does that mean you simply want to plot rectangles from minimum to maximum of the data?

Comment: Thanks - I may have slightly misunderstood how it treats outliers. My assumption was (a) That when making the boxplot it totally ignored the outliers in calculating quartiles when you're implying that instead (b) It includes those outliers in the calculations BUT because they fall outside of the whiskers, they are marked as points. In which case I assume (B) is correct?

Comment: Yes, all values are included in the calculation of quartiles.

Answer (score 1):

That would be inappropriate to extend the boxplot. The main thing about them is to show the quantiles, therefor an extension would make the boxplot statically wrong in its interpretation.

But you can remove the outliers with:

```
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

Comment: I agree about the apparent inappropriateness of what the OP appears to want.  An alternative to suppressing the outliers with `outlier.shape=NA` might be to extend the whiskers by setting `coef` to some appropriate large value.  That would at least maintain the impression of outlying data.  The components of a box plot (the box, the whisters, the outliers etc) have "standard" definitions.  Any movement from these standards risks confusing the reader, needs explanation and may be misleading..

Comment: Thanks - I may have slightly misunderstood how it treats outliers. My assumption was (a) That when making the boxplot it totally ignored the outliers in calculating quartiles when you're implying that instead (b) It includes those outliers in the calculations BUT because they fall outside of the whiskers, they are marked as points. 

In which case I assume (B) is correct?

Comment: The outliers are detected if their value is above Q3 + 1,5*IQR or below Q1-1,5*IQR (with IQR = Q3/Q1). The outliers are ALWAYS considered in the quantiles calculation, otherwise it would be very very wrong. The only time you can consider dropping outliers is when the outliers create a significant association in your model. But you have to explain why you choose to drop them and make sure your analysis takes that choice in consideration. I strongly advice to change your model instead of dropping them @AndrewCooke

Comment: Thank you - that's me being ignorant of the workings. In which case, they can be left. Thanks again.